# Как создать конструктор внутри объекта?

Tags: javascript

Существует объект который содержит объекты . В этом объекте есть метод который является конструктором при вызове которого просто добавляет еще объект.

```
var obj = {
            list1:{petName:'Gyffy', 
                    petOwner:'Peter',
                    date: '2016-05-03',
                    time: '14:23',
                    note:'sfdsfsdfdsf'},
            list2:{petName:'Catty', 
                    petOwner:'Oleg',
                    date: '2017-05-03',
                    time: '16:23',
                    note:'xcxzcxcxc'},
            addObj: function(petName,petOwner,date,time,note){
                    this.petName = petName,
                    this.petOwner = petOwner,
                    this.date = date,
                    this.time = time,
                    this.note = note
            }       
        }
        obj.addObj('Kitty','Max','2014-06-03','14:34','bla bla');
```

В результате этого "кода") создаются свойства текущего объекта.

```
{list1: {…}, list2: {…}, addObj: ƒ, petName: "Kitty", petOwner: "Max", …}
addObj
:
ƒ (petName,petOwner,date,time,note)
date
:
"2014-06-03"
list1
:
{petName: "Gyffy", petOwner: "Peter", date: "2016-05-03", time: "14:23", note: "sfdsfsdfdsf"}
list2
:
{petName: "Catty", petOwner: "Oleg", date: "2017-05-03", time: "16:23", note: "xcxzcxcxc"}
list3
:
{petName: "dsfdsf", petOwner: "Olga", date: "2018-12-06", time: "13:23", note: "dsfsd"}
note
:
"bla bla"
petName
:
"Kitty"
petOwner
:
"Max"
time
:
"14:34"
__proto__
:
Object
```

Как мне реализовать вызов конструктора и создать новый объект в `obj`

Comment: Не вполне понятно, какой результат Вы хотите получить. Возможно, что-то вроде такого: `obj.list3 = new obj.addObj('Kitty','Max','2014-06-03','14:34','bla bla');`?

Comment: @Yaant Да, совершенно верно Вы меня поняли! Все работает! Только появляется еще свойство `addObj`

Comment: Свойство `addObj` не "появляется", оно у вас прописано в исходном объекте.

Comment: @Yaant я имею ввиду в тех объектах которые созданы конструктором ! 
` addObj {petName: "Kitty", petOwner: "Max", date: "2014-06-03", time: "14:34", note: "bla bla"}`
А в объектах `list1  list2` нету `adobj`  
Я ничего против не имею) Я просто учусь и хотелось бы знать.Спасибо!

Comment: Да нет, не появляется. Вон внизу два ответа, нажмите "Выполнить код" и убедитесь, что никакого `addObj` в свежесозданных объектах нет. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  list1: {
    petName: 'Gyffy',
    petOwner: 'Peter',
    date: '2016-05-03',
    time: '14:23',
    note: 'sfdsfsdfdsf'
  },
  list2: {
    petName: 'Catty',
    petOwner: 'Oleg',
    date: '2017-05-03',
    time: '16:23',
    note: 'xcxzcxcxc'
  },
  addObj: function(petName, petOwner, date, time, note) {
    for (var i = 1; ; i++) {
      if (!this["list" + i]) {
        this["list" + i] = {
          petName: petName,
          petOwner: petOwner,
          date: date,
          time: time,
          note: note
        };
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

obj.addObj('Kitty', 'Max', '2014-06-03', '14:34', 'bla bla');
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите дёрнуть функцию в качестве конструктора, то вам нужно вызывать её с [new](https://learn.javascript.ru/constructor-new)

```js
var obj = {
    list1:{petName:'Gyffy', 
            petOwner:'Peter',
            date: '2016-05-03',
            time: '14:23',
            note:'sfdsfsdfdsf'},
    list2:{petName:'Catty', 
            petOwner:'Oleg',
            date: '2017-05-03',
            time: '16:23',
            note:'xcxzcxcxc'},
    addObj: function(petName,petOwner,date,time,note){
            this.petName = petName,
            this.petOwner = petOwner,
            this.date = date,
            this.time = time,
            this.note = note
    }       
}
obj.list3 = new obj.addObj('Kitty','Max','2014-06-03','14:34','bla bla');

console.log(obj);
```